# How to cast returned value of CreateInstance

Tags: c#, reflection, casting, createinstance

How does one cast the return value from CreateInstance when the type is unknown?

For example in this code:

```
MethodInfo mInfo = typeof(MyType).GetMethod(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
Object o = Activator.CreateInstance(mInfo.ReturnType);
```

how do I cast my o to whatever mInfo.ReturnType contains?

Comment: What you are planing to do with `o`? You have no need to cast it I think

Comment: I want to send it to the moon on a rocket made of cheese. Well, let's just assume I _do_ need to cast it. Why doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Casting it only makes sense if you know the type you want to cast it to (eg to assign it to a variable of that type). Anton's question was a legitimate one.

Comment: The code, at runtime, knows _exactly_ what type it should be. That's the whole point of using reflection in this way. And it is NEVER a legitimate question to ask "oooh, why do you wanna do that?" because it has no bearing whatsoever on your supposedly factual answer.

Comment: @Whatever - you are being abusive, *and* you are being technically... inaccurate. I've edited your comments. If you have a reflection use-case where the type is supposedly known, please show it.

Comment: The question has already been answered. While you were all sitting here wasting everyone's time with your noise.

Comment: @Whatever - the "answer" states the same thing as the comments. Asking you to clarify your intent is not "noise". It is fundamental to giving a useful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting (at least, in the way you usually mean) is a compile-time / static-typed operation. The only way that *even makes sense* at runtime with an unknown type is when dealing either with generics (casting it to some `T` - and note that you can choose the `T` at runtime via `MakeGenericMethod` or `MakeGenericType`), or with meta-programming (emitting IL to do the appropriate cast). In all other cases when the type is unknown until runtime, you are stuck with either `object` or `dynamic`.

Answer (score 0):

Commonly you cant do it in habitual manner, except situations `mInfo.ReturnType` contains definition of type which is visible in current context at compile time. For example if `mInfo.ReturnType` have `bool` definition you can simply do:

```
bool t = (bool)o;
```

But in this case there is no sence to use Activator. Activator class is used when you try to use type which was load from another assembly in other word the type is not visible at compile time.
So the answer you have no way to do this.